# How to fix JSON string uploading to S3 with contents of "[value: string]" rather than actual data

Tags: java, scala, amazon-s3, aws-java-sdk, aws-java-sdk-2.x

In Scala, I'm using the AWS Java SDK to upload a simple JSON string (containing a few rows of data from a database). The upload appears to work fine but the content of the uploaded file once it's in the S3 bucket is just "`[value: string]`" instead of the actual data. Before I upload I print the data out and confirm the data type is String. How do I fix this? I'm assuming it's one small tweak, but not sure what.

(I can't write the data to a file before upload, it has to be from the string, though I'd be willing to massage that into an InputStream or whatever, if need be - not sure how to do that though).

```
import com.amazonaws.services.s3.AmazonS3Client
import com.amazonaws.auth.BasicAWSCredentials
import com.amazonaws.ClientConfiguration

val query = "[My SQL query]";
val results = spark.sql(query);
val JSONdata = results.toJSON;

var JSONstring:String = JSONdata.toString;

try {
    println(JSONstring); // Displays my valid JSON data
    println(JSONstring.getClass); // Displays "class java.lang.String"
    val result = amazonS3Client.putObject(bucketName, objectKey, JSONstring);
    println("Result: " + result.getETag());
} catch {
    case e: Exception => println("Error: " + e.getMessage());
}
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

My suspicions is that instead of writing the actual string it tries to write the string object. Maybe it would work if you'd call the putObject method with a parameter of type byte array.
I think some of the answers [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2499132/how-to-write-a-string-to-amazon-s3-bucket) might help you